# icon tag styles not applying. I try to center the icon and change the color. but it is not working

Tags: html, css

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNorF.jpg) is the current status, I try to center and change the color of the icon, but this code is not working.

My HTML/CSS Codes

```css
.input-field i {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #dd1919;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-mail" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code works for you. I think what happened is that font awesome actually comments out your "i" tag. SO i selected it with the .fa-user class selector instead. Hope this works for you!

```css
.input-field .fa-user {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #dd1919;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-RXf+QSDCUQs5uwRKaDoXt55jygZZm2V++WUZduaU/Ui/9EGp3f/2KZVahFZBKGH0s774sd3HmrhUy+SgOFQLVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your E-mail" />
</div>
```